# SQLServer in-database R services: How do I get rxSummary to work properly?

Tags: sql-server, r

I'm trying to follow the tutorial for SQLServer in-database R services located here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt629161.aspx

However, when I run the rxSummary operation, instead of getting the expected data, I get the following:

```
Call:
rxSummary(formula = ~fare_amount:F(passenger_count, 1, 6), data = inDataSource)

Summary Statistics Results for: ~fare_amount:F(passenger_count, 1,
6)
Data: inDataSource (RxSqlServerData Data Source)
Number of valid observations: 1000 

 Name                                Mean  StdDev    Min Max ValidObs
 fare_amount:F_passenger_count_1_6_T 5.952 0.4979397 5.5 6.5 1000    
 MissingObs
 0         

Statistics by category (6 categories):

 Category                                   F_passenger_count_1_6_T Means
 fare_amount for F(passenger_count,1,6,T)=1 1                       5.952
 fare_amount for F(passenger_count,1,6,T)=2 2                          NA
 fare_amount for F(passenger_count,1,6,T)=3 3                          NA
 fare_amount for F(passenger_count,1,6,T)=4 4                          NA
 fare_amount for F(passenger_count,1,6,T)=5 5                          NA
 fare_amount for F(passenger_count,1,6,T)=6 6                          NA
 StdDev    Min Max ValidObs
 0.4979397 5.5 6.5 1000    
    NA  NA  NA    0    
    NA  NA  NA    0    
    NA  NA  NA    0    
    NA  NA  NA    0    
    NA  NA  NA    0
```

I know that the actual data exists in the database correctly because I can select rows with passenger counts other than 1.

Furthermore, after running the command, the DB machine has a SQL Launchpad Service that jumps to 100% CPU usage for about 10 minutes.  During this time, you can't query the database.

What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the SQL select statement that creates the data set is wrong in the tutorial.  It selects only the top 1000 rows, and those happen to all have passenger count of 1.  In order to get the real results, you have to select every row, or get a random sample by selecting a subset and adding an ORDER BY NEWID() to the end.